# Merge 2 arrays with null values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to merge 2 tables I show you an example:

```
foreach ($dashboardData as $item) {
    $results[$item['month']] = [
        DashboardConsts::COLUMN_MONTHLY => $item['month'] ?? null,
        DashboardConsts::ROW_NBR => $item['nbr'] ?? null,
        DashboardConsts::ROW_SELL_PRICE => $item['sum'] ?? null,
        'number' => $item['countNewBc'] ?? null,
    ];
}

array:2 [▼
  "2020-12" => array:4 [▼
    "Mois" => "2020-12"
    "Nbr vendus" => null
    "CA TTC" => null
    "number" => "1"
  ]
  "2021-01" => array:4 [▼
    "Mois" => "2021-01"
    "Nbr vendus" => null
    "CA TTC" => null
    "number" => "2"
  ]
]
```

and

```
"2020-12" => array:4 [▼
  "Mois" => "2020-12"
  "Nbr vendus" => "1"
  "CA TTC" => "790"
  "number" => null
]
"2021-01" => array:4 [▼
  "Mois" => "2021-01"
  "Nbr vendus" => "3"
  "CA TTC" => "1680"
  "number" => null
]
```

Basically here, I make a sort of group my values ​​by period, I try to merge my 2 arrays to ensure that the fields which are 'null'.

I want to replace null values ​​with those that are filled in one of the array.

I had to try to do something like that :

```
$tableau1  = array_filter($tableau1);
$tableau2  = array_filter($tableau2);
$result = array_merge($tableau1, $tableau2);
```

but it does not work.

EDIT:

I wish my final result looks like this

```
array:2 [▼
  "2020-12" => array:4 [▼
    "Mois" => "2020-12"
    "Nbr vendus" => "1"
    "CA TTC" => "790"
    "number" => "1"
  ]
  "2021-01" => array:4 [▼
    "Mois" => "2021-01"
    "Nbr vendus" => "3"
    "CA TTC" => "1680"
    "number" => "2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want the finished array to look like? Or label which one is the input arrays, and which one is the final array.

Comment: i just edited my request, i dont realy know which one is the final array, both can be the final array i think

Comment: Okay great. What happens if both values are not null? Which array should take the values go in to the final? Or, do they never overlap? Either way, I'll post an answer below. Also, what happens if both array's are null?

Comment: oh ok i understand, the array 2 is the final, the first one can have emply value ( like the key "number" can have no value) but the second array always have value ( like "CA TTC", Nbr vendus")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of achieving this, all the solutions, needs to go through the arrays, one way or another.

You easily do a `foreach ()` loop marathon and and loads of `if ()` statements to make sure the conversion is correctly made.

Anyways, this is my take on the question.

Remove `null` values and replace them with [`array_replace_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php):

```
<?php

function array_remove_null($input) { 
  foreach ($input as &$value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $value = array_remove_null($value); 
    }
  }
  return array_filter($input, function($item){
    return $item !== null && $item !== '';
  }); 
}

/**
 * Using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php
 */

$array1 = [
    "2020-12" => [
        "Mois" => "2020-12",
        "Nbr vendus" => null,
        "CA TTC" => null,
        "number" => "1",
    ],
    "2021-01" => [
        "Mois" => "2021-01",
        "Nbr vendus" => null,
        "CA TTC" => null,
        "number" => "2",
    ],
];

$array2 = [
    "2020-12" => [
        "Mois" => "2020-12",
        "Nbr vendus" => "1",
        "CA TTC" => "790",
        "number" => null,
    ],
    "2021-01" => [
        "Mois" => "2021-01",
        "Nbr vendus" => "3",
        "CA TTC" => "1680",
        "number" => null,
    ],
];

$array = array_replace_recursive(array_remove_null($array1), array_remove_null($array2));

var_dump($array);
```

In action: https://3v4l.org/WJnYu

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand. You need a nested loop to access both sets of data. The following might not be the actual answer, but it's close.

```
$results = array();
foreach ($inputArrayOne as $onekey => $arrayOne) {
    $temp_results = array();
    foreach ($inputArrayTwo as $twokey => $arrayTwo) {
        if ($onekey != $twokey) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!is_null($arrayOne['month'])) {
            $temp_results['Mois'] = $arrayOne['month'];
        } else if (!is_null($arrayTwo['month'])) {
            $temp_results['Mois'] = $arrayTwo['month'];
        } else {
            $temp_results['Mois'] = null;   // to account for bad data
        }
        if (!is_null($arrayOne['nbr'])) {
            $temp_results['Nbr vendus'] = $arrayOne['nbr'];
        } else if (!is_null($arrayTwo['nbr'])) {
            $temp_results['Nbr vendus'] = $arrayTwo['nbr'];
        } else {
            $temp_results['Nbr vendus'] = null; // to account for bad data
        }
        if (!is_null($arrayOne['sum'])) {
            $temp_results['CA TTC'] = $arrayOne['sum'];
        } else if (!is_null($arrayTwo['sum'])) {
            $temp_results['CA TTC'] = $arrayTwo['sum'];
        } else {
            $temp_results['CA TTC'] = null; // to account for bad data
        }
        if (!is_null($arrayOne['countNewBc'])) {
            $temp_results['number'] = $arrayOne['countNewBc'];
        } else if (!is_null($arrayTwo['countNewBc'])) {
            $temp_results['number'] = $arrayTwo['countNewBc'];
        } else {
            $temp_results['number'] = null; // to account for bad data
        }
    }
    $results[$arrayOne['month']] = $temp_results;
}
```

Comment: There might need to be a comparison in the nested loop to check that you're on the correct index. I'll add that shortly. Also, I might be off on values by one set of index.

Comment: FYI - I never use classes in php, so you'll have to figure that part out for yourself.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I have chosen the other answer cause it was easier for using but yours was good too

Comment: You're welcome. I understand, when I saw the other answer, I liked how it was shorter as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know you got your answer, but if someone stumbles upon this question and don't need recursive (only one level down in array) check then you could do this:
*(My logic is simply to replace null with zeros and add together equivalent keys from the arrays. In my code I also take for granted that there are same the same keys in inner array for each array)*

```
$new_arr = array_slice($array1,0);
foreach($array1 as $headkey=>$item) {
    foreach($item as $innerkey=>$it) {
        $null_change = false;
        if ($array1[$headkey][$innerkey] === null) {
            $array1[$headkey][$innerkey] == 0;
            $null_change = true;
        }
        if ($array2[$headkey][$innerkey] === null) {
            $array2[$headkey][$innerkey] == 0;
            $null_change = true;
        }
        
        if ($null_change === true) {
            $new_arr[$headkey][$innerkey] = $array1[$headkey][$innerkey] + 
            $array2[$headkey][$innerkey];
        } 
    }
}
var_dump($new_arr);
```

If you need a more generic result based on unknown number of arrays you could do this (but still only one level in each array):

```
function replaceNullOccurences(...$arrays) {
    if (!is_array($arrays[0])) return;
    $new_arr = array_slice($arrays[0],0);
    foreach($arrays[0] as $headkey=>$item) {
        foreach($item as $innerkey=>$it) {
            $null_change = false;
            foreach($arrays as $arr) {
                if ($arr[$headkey][$innerkey] === null) {
                    $arr[$headkey][$innerkey] == 0; //Change null to zero for addition below
                    $null_change = true;
                }
            }
            //If null in the key in any array, sum together the arrays
            if ($null_change === true) {
                foreach($arrays as $arr) {            
                    $new_arr[$headkey][$innerkey] += $arr[$headkey][$innerkey];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $new_arr;        
}

$result = replaceNullOccurences($array1, $array2);
```